# Get the table(only values) from two different tables?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, beautifulsoup

I want to get or select data from two different tables with same class.I tried getting it from 'soup.find_all' but formatting the data is getting tough.
There are two tables with same class. I need to get only values(not label) from the tables.

TABLE 1:

```html
<div class="bh_collapsible-body" style="display: none;">
  <table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" class="prop-list">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="item">
        <table>
          <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="label">Rim Material</td>
            <td class="value">Alloy</td>
          </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td class="item">
        <table>
          <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="label">Front Tyre Description</td>
            <td class="value">215/55 R16</td>
          </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="item">
        <table>
          <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="label">Front Rim Description</td>
            <td class="value">16x7.0</td>
          </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td class="item">
        <table>
          <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="label">Rear Tyre Description</td>
            <td class="value">215/55 R16</td>
          </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="item">
        <table>
          <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="label">Rear Rim Description</td>
            <td class="value">16x7.0</td>
          </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
</div>
```

TABLE 2:

```html
<div class="bh_collapsible-body" style="display: none;">
  <table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" class="prop-list">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="item">
        <table>
          <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="label">Steering</td>
            <td class="value">Rack and Pinion</td>
          </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
</div>
```

What i have tried:

I tried getting the first table contents from Xpath but its giving with both values and labels.

```
table1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='features']/div/div[5]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]")
```

I tried to split the data but not succeeded

Comment: try xpath:  driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id='features']//table//td[@class="value"]').text

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for CSS selector `tr:not(:has(tr))`, this will select the inner-most `<tr>`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser') # the variable data contains string for Table1 and Table2 in your question

rows = []
for tr in soup.select('tr:not(:has(tr))'):
    rows.append([td.get_text(strip=True) for td in tr.select('td')])

for row in zip(*rows):
    print(''.join('{: ^25}'.format(d) for d in row))
```

Prints:

```
  Rim Material        Front Tyre Description    Front Rim Description    Rear Tyre Description    Rear Rim Description           Steering         
      Alloy                 215/55 R16                 16x7.0                 215/55 R16                 16x7.0               Rack and Pinion
```

The variable `rows` contains:

```
[['Rim Material', 'Alloy'],
 ['Front Tyre Description', '215/55 R16'],
 ['Front Rim Description', '16x7.0'],
 ['Rear Tyre Description', '215/55 R16'],
 ['Rear Rim Description', '16x7.0'],
 ['Steering', 'Rack and Pinion']]
```

Further reading:

**[CSS Selectors Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)**

EDIT: Changed to CSS Selector to `tr:not(:has(tr))`

Comment: I'm geting this NotImplementedError: Only the following pseudo-classes are implemented: nth-of-type.

Comment: @thoris Make sure you have latest version of BeautifulSoup. I'm on version `beautifulsoup4==4.8.0`

Comment: @thoris It's not possible. Type `pip freeze` to see actual version. Also, are you running Python from virtual environment or Jupyter notebook? That could be the reason you have version mismatch.

Comment: I'm running it from jupyter, both in terminal(v env) and jupyter the version's same  4.8.0

Comment: @thoris Run this code `import bs4; print(bs4.__version__)`, this will show what version you are running in the script. Also the `soupsieve` dependency should be on version `soupsieve==1.9.2`